# How to fetch Images from CoreData correct?

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimageview, fetch

this is the code how I save images in CoreData:

```
lazy var dataImage = profileIcon.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    
    //MARK: - Saving the Workout Image
    
    func savePUValues() {
        // Kontext Identifiziern
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entityName = "PushUps" //Tabellenname im DatenModell
    
        
        //Neuen Datensatz anlegen:
        guard let newEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)
        else {
            return
        }
        
        let newSet = NSManagedObject(entity: newEntity, insertInto: context)
        
        
        let savingImage = dataImage
        
        
        newSet.setValue(savingImage, forKey: "image")
        
        // Datensatz speichern
        do {
        try context.save()
       
        } catch {
            print("An error appeared")
        }
    }
```

Now I want to fetch the image data and load it into a UITableView:
With this code:

```
 func loadValues() -> [CellData] {
        //Kontext identifizieren
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
        //Anfrage stellen
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entityName = "PushUps"
        
        
        //MARK: - Request 
        
        // Use a specific fetch request
        let request = NSFetchRequest<PushUps>(entityName: entityName)
        // add a sort descriptor to sort the items by highScore descending
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "count", ascending: false)]
        
        do {
            // results is an array of PushUps instances, no type cast needed
            let results = try context.fetch(request)
            for r in results {
                if let result = r as? NSManagedObject {
                    
     
                        
                    
                    let titletext = "\(count!) Push-Ups"
                    
                    var cellTitleLabel = UILabel()
                    cellTitleLabel.text = titletext
                    
                   
                    
                    let workoutImage = result.value(forKey: "image") as? UIImageView
                    
                    
                
                    
                    print("Image was loaded into the array")
                    var Data1 = CellData(imageData: workoutImage ?? oImageView, titleData: cellTitleLabel)
                    print("Image: \(String(describing: workoutImage)), TitLe: \(cellTitleLabel) ")
                    cellDataArray.append(Data1)
                }
            }
            

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        
        return cellDataArray
    }
```

The problem is that the it's loading the image as nil.
The console is giving me this back: "Image: nil, TitLe: <UILabel: 0x115f17980; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = '0.0 Push-Ups'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x28249cfa0>> "

So where is the problem? What is wrong with my Code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are saving Data and trying to retrieve it as a UIImageView, which is doomed to failure:

```
lazy var dataImage = profileIcon.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
// Data
let savingImage = dataImage
newSet.setValue(savingImage, forKey: "image")
// still Data
// ---------------------
let workoutImage = result.value(forKey: "image") as? UIImageView
// UIImageView?????
```

However, *don't* save image data into Core Data in the first place. Save to disk and store the partial path (e.g. the file name).

Comment: What do you mean with ,,Save to disk"? One which ,,disk" should I save the pictures of the users??

Comment: Anywhere you like. You are sandboxed, the disk belongs to you.

Comment: So the problem is that I'm working with CoreData? Should I use the cloudKit instead?

Comment: If you have reason to use Core Data (i.e. you have a persistent complex object graph backing your app), use it. If you are using it _only_ because you have some data to save persistently, that's a waste.